# Kabeja 0.4 How to save changes?

Tags: java, dxf, kabeja

wrote a simple code using the Kabeja library. The code reads an existing dxf file, creates text and adds it to a new layer, the real question is how to save changes to dxf?

```
public class DXFLayerTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        File file = new File("D:\\11.016571.DXF");
        File out = new File("D:\\11.016571ADDL.DXF");

        try ( FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            Parser parser = ParserBuilder.createDefaultParser();
            parser.parse(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            DXFDocument document = parser.getDocument();

            DXFText text = new DXFText();
            text.setText("SOME-PART-ID");

            text.setHeight(5.0); 
            text.setRotation(0); 

            DXFLayer layer = new DXFLayer();
            layer.setName("engraving");
            layer.setColor(0xC3C3C3); 

            layer.addDXFEntity(text);

            document.addDXFLayer(layer);
            document.addDXFEntity(text);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Found example

```
        import org.kabeja.dxf.DXFWriter;
...
        DXFWriter writer = new DXFWriter();
        File file = new File("output.dxf");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        writer.write(document, fos);
```

but there is no DXFWriter in the library Kabeja 0.4

The output is expected to be a new dxf file containing the added entities